# How to send internal storage images

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

I want to use this code to send images to the internal storage directory

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/Camera");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    images.add(listOfFiles[i].getPath());
                }
            }
```

When using this code gives the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

But the photos are in the internal storage

**Where's the problem please help me thanks**

Comment: "But the photos are in the internal storage" -- they are on what the Android SDK calls [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: `File folder = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera);` not work

Comment: [please answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5988526/bashir)